# How to imnplement QuickReturn View with listview and actionBar

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to implement the quick return view with ListView. I have searched a lot and found the Roman Nuricks tutorial but that is with Scrollview. I want the same implementsation with my listview and i am also having the ActionBarActivity Extended to use Custom ActionBar. I have gone through following two links but not found anything that worked for me. Please help.

[RomanNurik scrollableview](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt)

[QuickReturnListView](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView)

Comment: you go to two links and you said _but not found anything that worked for me_ very strange to believe.

Comment: in the second link the mainactivity is extending the FragmentActivity while i need to have ActionBarActivity